# Looking for help comprehending why this dict comprehension fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.4

I'm looking for some help comprehending why this won't work. It seems like python won't create keys in an existing dict in a dictionary comprehension, but that sounds like a bad joke.. more likely, I'm just missing something.

So here I am. Stuck with this:

```
## let's say, for the sake of argument: len(bigstr.split('\n')) < 1000 
indexed = {1000:'stuff', 1001:'in here', 1002:'lots', 1003:'of it'}
{indexed[idx]:item.strip() for idx, item in enumerate(bigstr.split('\n'))}
```

Which would work (as opposed to firing a `KeyError: 0`, if it were written like:

```
indexed = {1000:'stuff', 1001:'in here', 1002:'lots', 1003:'of it'}
for idx, item in enumerate(bigstr.split('\n')):
    indexed[idx] = item.strip()
```

In fact, so well would the previous snippet work, that it makes the first one work. Amazing!

So I thought I'd get smart and do something (in a fresh session) like:

```
indexed = {1000:'stuff', 1001:'in here', 1002:'lots', 1003:'of it'}
new_items_only = {indices[idx]:item.strip() for idx, item in enumerate(bigstr.split('\n'))}
```

Expecting it to work, because perhaps it just wouldn't work with an existing dict (which is kinda what I'm going for here)?

Alas, no dice.

Now, I should mention that I know that if I do this:

```
indices = {indices:item.strip() for idx, item in enumerate(bigstr.split('\n'))}
```

I can get that dict to happen, but I would like to add the keys into an existing dict, you know? .. Actually, do you know? Can you help me comprehend this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
>>> indexed = {1000:'stuff', 1001:'in here', 1002:'lots', 1003:'of it'}
>>> bigstr = 'x\ny\nz'
>>> indexed.update({idx:item.strip() for idx, item in enumerate(bigstr.split('\n'))})
>>> indexed
{0: 'x', 1: 'y', 2: 'z', 1000: 'stuff', 1001: 'in here', 1002: 'lots', 1003: 'of it'}
```

Comment: Oh nice.. That'll do it. Definitely what I was missing. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for pointing me at update, definitely did the trick.